# Is there a good word for a square-rectangle relationship?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Any given square is always a rectangle, but a rectangle isn't necessarily a square, so squares and rectangles have a *_* relationship. I've been noticing this sort of thing everywhere ever since I noticed that I didn't know a good word for it. I've been calling it a container relationship because one class of things is contained within a larger class of things. However, a "container" relationship doesn't sound very good and doesn't really convey the meaning on its own. A more elegant word would be helpful.

Edit:
A specific definition would be something like: a is always b. b is sometimes a.

Comment: A rectangle is an *abstraction* (loosening of constraints) of a square. The relationship of a rectangle to a square is *intransitive* (only goes one direction).  That said, I'm sure there must be a common, well-established word for the generalization/specialization relationship; if not from philosophy, then from logic, or mathematics.

Comment: @DanBron I like your answer better than mine, but yes, there is a mathematical/logical word, it is "subset" (intransitive) and "set" being the outer (abstraction layer)

Comment: @Mike, good one.  Also worth pointing out that there is a category of logical fallacies (syllogistic fallacies) which surround the idea of transitive relationships and subsets; one relevant fallacy is known as the "[illicit major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illicit_major)".

Comment: @DanBron I really like intransitive. I wouldn't have thought of that. It would definitely be nice to find something less formal sounding, but that would definitely work.

Comment: @DanDavis, depends on how informal you want to be, but certainly "one way" is candidate.

Comment: This doesn't fit into the blank (a ___ relationship), but, to expand on Dan's first comment: A square is a *special case* of a rectangle.

Comment: In Object Oriented programming this is an ["is a"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship.

Comment: If you're coming from programming you should note that squares are not rectangles. /cc @MartinSmith

Comment: @djechlin In programming, whether an "is a" relationship between squares and rectangles is appropriate, depends on the design. Saying it's appropriate without further info is wrong. Saying it's inappropriate without further info is also wrong.

Comment: I've managed for 65 years now with "sorta kinda like".

Comment: @djechlin Only because what most programmers call a square is not really a square. Shapes are immutable things, like numbers. Programmers create mutable things that are shaped like squares and rectangles and then get surprised that geometric relationships don't apply.

Comment: @Doval: More precisely, an *immutable* ("read-only") square is-a rectangle, a hypothetical "write-only" rectangle is-a square, but a mutable rectangle isn't a square and neither is a mutable square a rectangle. This is a consequence of the co- and contravariance rules of the Liskov Substitution Principle. (Note: I have no idea what a write-only geometric shape would be useful for, the only write-only things I know are stuff like loggers and output streams.)

Comment: I like how, in this comment thread, people have managed to confuse "programming" and "object oriented programming". Especially since the people getting most persnickety about subtyping relationships are the ones guiltiest of that failure to distinguish. What if I'm programming in a pure functional language? Or assembly? Or C? [Where is you Liskov now?](http://memearchive.net/memerial.net/630/your-god-where-is-he-now.jpg)

Answer (score 38):

You can utilize the word "subset" for this usage.

Squares are a "subset" of Rectangles.

Meaning, they are within the "set" of Rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares.

Taken from Google Define:

sub·set
ˈsəbˌset
noun
noun: subset;
plural noun: subsets;
noun: sub-set;
plural noun: sub-sets
**DEFINTION**

*a part of a larger group of related things.*

> synonyms: subcategory, branch, subdivision, subsection, subsidiary

**Examples:**

"the quartet is a subset of our orchestral group"

Usage in MATHEMATICS

a set of which all the elements are contained in another set.

Comment: This is a good one. I suppose it's problematic for me that I don't have a specific context that I'd like to use this word in other than in my own head. So anything works. It's as much an aesthetic choice as a practical one.

Comment: @DanDavis I've added some Synonyms too, they might aid you in finding a word more fitting. :)

Comment: Oh, a subsidiary relationship has a nice ring to it, even it is a mouthful. Thanks, I like that.

Comment: Google Define is not a citable reference, because it gives different results to different people at different times, and sometimes even to the same people at different times.  You must cite an actual dictionary.

Comment: _Subset_ is definitely the right word to use to describe the square, and I would call the rectangle a _superset_; but the real question here is whether there is a word for the **relationship** between a subset and a superset. You wouldn't say that _square_ and _rectangle_ have a subset relationship (or, pace Dan's suggestion, a subsidiary relationship), so as a strict answer to the question, I fear it doesn't work.

Comment: A word for the relationship between a superset and a subset is ***hierarchical***.

Comment: The sense in which the quartet is a subset of our orchestral group is different to the sense in which a square is a type of rectangle.

Comment: It can also be helpful to realize that rectangles are a *generalization* of squares.  Rectangles are what you get if you *keep* the restriction of right angles, but relax the restriction of equal length sides.  The rhombus is another generalization when you relax the angles but not the lengths. There are lots of possibilities.  It's good to note that rectangle isn't the only superset of square, and that not every pair of supersets of square have a subclass/superclass relationship with each other.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Also worth noting that the converse of the *generalization* relationship is that squares are a *special case* of rectangles.

Comment: @Jules Indeed!  It's not really on-topic for this site, but in a particular field of artificial intelligence, namely *conjecture generation* (e.g., see [*Automated Mathematician*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Mathematician)), the techniques of generalizing or specializing have been used to generate "interesting" concepts.

Comment: "Meaning, they are within the "set" of Rectangles, but they are not all rectangles." <- this is wrong, all squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares.

Comment: @JakeSellers What are you talking about, that's exactly what that sentence says. "Meaning, they (squares) are within the "set" of Rectangles, but they(square) are not all (kinds of) rectangles.

In any case, I've edited my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 17):

*Square* is a ***hyponym*** of *rectangle*, which is a ***hypernym*** of *square*.  The wikipedia article *[Hyponymy and hypernymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy)* says

> In linguistics, a **hyponym** is a word or phrase whose semantic field is included within that of another word, its **hypernym** (sometimes spelled hyperonym outside of the natural language processing community). In simpler terms, a hyponym shares a *type-of* relationship with its hypernym. For example, "pigeon", "crow", "eagle" and "seagull" are all hyponyms of "bird" (their hypernym); which, in turn, is a hyponym of "animal".

*Edit:*  For more precision, one should add qualifying phrases like “the word” or “the set”:

- the word *square* is a ***hyponym*** of the word *rectangle*
- the set of squares is a ***subset*** of the set of rectangles

However, I think *subclass* [a term mentioned in Joshua Taylor's comments] can be used without added qualifiers.[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subclass#Noun) gives the following definition of *subclass* relevant within computing:  “In object-oriented programming, an object class derived from another class (its superclass) from which it inherits a base set of properties and methods”.

- squares are a ***subclass*** of rectangles

Speaking mathematically, a class is a less-determinate category or collection of things than is a set.  From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/class), *class* means “A group, collection, category or set sharing characteristics or attributes”, and *[subclass](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subclass)* means “A rank directly below class”.

Comment: I'm uneasy with this usage (I was hoping nobody would suggest it). Knife and cutlery, chair and furniture, sock and clothing, certainly: but set terminology seems far more appropriate for use in the mathematical field. Terms are almost always well-defined in maths, whereas one person's 'hurricane' may be a hyponym of another person's. And many public squares aren't even rectangular.

Comment: This is the English Language & Usage group, and these terms are about sets of semantic meaning, and as such are also mathematically appropriate!

Comment: I wouldn't ever recommend those words, the will just be perceived as jargon... and they are phonically close with like every pair of hyper/hypo words...

Comment: These are the perfect terms to describe the relationship between the words *square* and *rectangle*, though perhaps not for the relationship between squares and rectangles themselves.

Comment: @Grady I think saying *every* pair is a bit of hypobole. I mean... crap...

Answer (score 11):

A square is a special type, or a specialisation of rectangle.

A rectangle is a more general type, a generalisation of a square.

They are in a hierarchical relationship. They are in a specialisation relationship.

Answer (score 6):

The relationship between a square and a rectangle is "type of".   A square is a type of rectangle, but a rectangle is not a type of square.

I'm not aware of a single word that means "type of".

In engineering and programming circles, this relationship is also described as "is a".   Another similar relationship in this context is are "has a".

A rectangle definitely does not "contain" a square, in the sense of the original question: that would be the wrong thing to say to mean that a square is a type of rectangle.   When you say "a rectangle contains a square" you mean "has a" not "is a".

It's also "obscure" to think of a "square" as a subset of a "rectangle".   The set of squares might be a subset of the set of rectangles, but "square" and "rectangle" in this context are types (of shapes), not sets.

Comment: The question didn't claim that a rectangle contains a square, only that the class of rectangles contains the class of squares, which is true.

Comment: I was addressing the questions use of the term "container".  My point is that the relationship between a rectangle and a square is not about "containment" - it is about "type of".    It surely is the case the the _set_ of all possible rectangles contains the set off all possible squares, but (despite the most popular answer!) it is not the case that the relationship the question is looking for is one of "subset".   A single square is a "type of "rectangle", completely independent from the existence of or consideration of "sets".

Answer (score 5):

There are different ways to think about this:

You can consider the set of all squares and the set of all rectangles and how they overlap with one another. In mathematical jargon we would say *Squares are a **proper subset** of rectangles.* or *Rectangles are a **proper superset** of squares.*

In normal, non-technical English, *Squares are a **subset** of rectangles.* will generally be understood to mean this.

You can also consider the meanings of *square* and *rectangle* and how they relate to one another. The meaning of *square* can be expressed in terms of being a rectangle with additional restriction: A square is an equilateral rectangle. So the relationship could be expressed as:  *A square is a **kind of** rectangle*.  There are a wide range of other ways of expressing *kind of*.  Depending on the direction, the relationship itself is called *specialization* or *generalization*.

Most people are more comfortable expressing things in terms of subsets or specialization than they are in terms of supersets or generalization. So unless you are in a technical context, or the direction is very important to your meaning, it's best to stick to expressing these relationships in terms of specialization.

Comment: Do not forget that Squares are also a subset of Rhombi.

Comment: @Victor It's not particularly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The relation is called ***inclusion***.  A set *includes* all of its subsets. The set of rectangles includes the set of squares.

Expressed in terms of ***membership***, each *member* of a subset of a set *S* is also a *member* of *S*. Each square is a rectangle.

(And a set includes itself as a subset. A **proper** subset of a set *S* is a subset that is not the same as *S*.)

Expressed in terms of predicates, the relation is ***implication***. Being a square implies being a rectangle; squareness implies rectangleness.

Answer (score 2):

A square is special case of rectangles.

As Mike said, subset is correct. In my opinion, by saying special case the uniqueness of squares amongst rectangles can be emphasised.

Answer (score 2):

They share a "specialization" relationship if you want to use a software term.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same original question as you. Perhaps "mutual inclusion" or "mutually inclusive."
I wad having an argument with someone when I said I liked to ride motorcycles because they are fun, and she replied "oh, it's a game to you?" Games are fun, leading her to this conclusion. But, not all fun derives from games. Fun can come from other forms. I thought about the rectangle/square relation, and it amazed me that I didn't know the term for their relationship. After reading the responses here, saying that two things are not mutually inclusive seems like a reasonable phrase.

JH