# A is "nested" in B, B is ... A?

Tags: terminology

When something is a subelement of another, we can say that it is nested into something. But how about the opposite way?

A is nested in B

B is .... A

Would the word be "nesting"?

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: [Square-rectangle relationship](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196584)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know sub/super specification mathematically, I'm just asking for the english word of that relationship with respect to the word "nested".

Comment: *Wraps*, *envelopes*, *encompasses*,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"B is nesting A" or "B nests A" works. If you don't want to use that, consider:

> B is encompassing A

or rather

> B **encompasses** A.

It works for both the physical and metaphorical sense.

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/encompass):

> 1. Surround and have or ***hold within***
>
> 1.1 Include comprehensively

Answer (score 2):

I would probably say ***B includes A***; or ***B incorporates A***.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more options:

**B contains A**

**B is the parent of A** (for the case when A is a subtype of B)